# Maximum set of edges or vertices that doesn't disconnect graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

A graph is k-connected if every set of fewer than k vertices does not disconnect
the graph, and a graph is k-edge-connected if every set of fewer than k edges
does not disconnect the graph. The connectivity of a graph is the largest
k for which it is k-connected, and the edge-connectivity of a graph is the
largest k for which it is k-edge-connected.

I'm interested in the related concept of the largest k for which some set of 
k edges in a connected graph does not disconnect the graph (though other sets 
of k or fewer edges might disconnect the graph). In a cursory internet search, I 
couldn't find anything on this (or the related concept for vertices), so I'm
asking here whether this has already been studied and given a name (or several
names by different people who studied it independently)? If so, what is it
called, and what is known about how to characterize graphs with a 
non-disconnecting set of k edges, how to find the largest size of a 
non-disconnecting set of edges, or how to find an actual non-disconnecting 
set of edges of maximum size?

If a graph G has a Hamiltonian path, then the largest non-disconnecting set
has $|E(G)| - |V(G)| + 1$ edges (namely, for any Hamiltonian path of G, all 
edges except those on the Hamiltonian path). For a tree T there are no
non-disconnecting sets of edges. But what about graphs that are not trees
and have no Hamiltonian paths?

Note that the corresponding concept for vertices would have to be a set of
vertices such that neither it nor any of its subsets disconnects the graph,
as otherwise every set of $|V(G)| - 1$ vertices would be a maximum size
non-disconnecting set.

As an example of the difference between these concepts and k-connectivity and
k-edge-connectivity, the complete graph on n vertices $K_n$ is n-connected
and n-edge-connected. If the vertices are labeled $v_0$ to $v_{n-1}$, consider
the graph obtained by subdividing the edge $\{v_0,v_1\}$, replacing it with
two edges $\{v_0,u\}$ and $\{u,v_1\}$. This new graph is 2-connected and
2-edge-connected, as deleting the two vertices $v_0$ and $v_1$ leaves $u$ as an
isolated vertex, as does deleting the two edges $\{v_0,u\}$ and $\{u,v_1\}$.
However, the set of n-1 vertices $v_1$ to $v_{n-1}$ is one whose deletion doesn't 
disconnect the graph, nor does the deletion of any of its subsets. Similarly, 
the set of edges containing all $\{v_i,v_j\}$ for which $i+1 \lt j$ is a set
of ${n-1 \choose 2}$ edges that disconnects neither $K_n$ nor the new graph.

This issue arose when I was looking at classes of graphs that have the same
degree sequences and the same edge-degrees sequences (not a standard terminology,
but I'm using it to mean pairs of degrees of the edges' incident vertices). I
wanted to set a canonical representation of a class as one with the fewest
number of components, and I found that if I started with an arbitrary graph of a class I could reduce the number of its components without changing the degree or edge-degrees sequences by replacing $\{v_0,v_1\}$ in one component and $\{u_0,u_1\}$
in another component, where $deg(v_0) = deg(u_0)$ and $deg(v_1) = deg(u_1)$,
with $\{v_0,u_1\}$ and $\{u_0,v_1\}$. This only actually reduces the number of
components if at least one of the old edges being replaced is not a bridge in
its component. So, in the case where a bunch of the components are trees, I
wanted to know how many tree components the non-tree component could absorb.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after posting the question, I realized that the answer is simple enough that maybe no one bothered to give the concept a name (at least in the edges case that prompted me to ask it). If a graph G is connected, it has a spanning tree, which has $|V(G)| - 1$ edges just as a Hamiltonian path would, and the edges of G other than in the spanning tree would be a set of maximum size $|E(G)| - |V(G)| + 1$ whose deletion doesn't disconnect G. Thus the number is easy to find, and the algorithms for finding a set are basically those for finding a spanning tree.